# How to calculate the accuracy of Random forest and H2O Gradient boosted model

Tags: r

// Using the following codes I am able to predict the Sales and create the file. But I want to calculate the overall model accuracy to see how the test set(test1)  performed. Below are the full codes from rstudio.

```
//So here are two data set 1)train 2) test. And the task is to predict the sales.

//All the data set can be found here https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/data
```

// RF was trained on train data with selected features and then Sales of test data was predicted.

// Any way to calculate the accuracy of the prediction (RF model) So i can compare that accuracy with H2O. Gradient boost model? I seem to be lost.

````
//Thanks a bunch.



```{r,echo=TRUE,message=F, warning=F}
library(readr)
library(randomForest)
set.seed(415)
```

Reading the CSV files to be analyzed 

```{r,echo=TRUE,message=F, warning=F}
train <- read_csv("train.csv")
test  <- read_csv("test.csv")
store <- read_csv("store.csv")

##merging the two files because two files have the different feature that have to be combined in order to the see the full effect of features on sales.
train1 <- merge(train,store) 
test1 <- merge(test,store)
```


Converting all the 'NA' in train data to Zeros. Store 622 has 11 missing values for the "open" column, in test data; so to predict correctly I have decided to input "1" for open column of store 622. Otherwise our prediction will not be correct.

```{r}


train1[is.na(train1)]   <- 0
test1[is.na(test1)]   <- 1

## We will only look at the stores that had status as "open"
train1<- train1[ which(train1$Open=='1'),]
```

train1 and test1 data have "Date" as column value. We will seperate the Date into month, year and day respectively. These new variables generated through "Date" column will be better handle to predict the sales 

```{r}

train1$Date <- as.Date(train1$Date)
test1$Date <- as.Date(test1$Date)

train1$month <- as.integer(format(train1$Date, "%m"))
train1$year <- as.integer(format(train1$Date, "%y"))
train1$day <- as.integer(format(train1$Date, "%d"))
train1$DayOfYear <- as.integer(as.POSIXlt(train1$Date)$yday)
train1$week <- as.integer( format(train1$Date+3, "%U"))


test1$month <- as.integer(format(test1$Date, "%m"))
test1$year <- as.integer(format(test1$Date, "%y"))
test1$day <- as.integer(format(test1$Date, "%d"))
test1$DayOfYear <-  as.integer(as.POSIXlt(test1$Date)$yday)
test1$week <- as.integer( format(test1$Date+3, "%U"))
```


```{r}

names(train1)
summary(train1)

names(test1)
summary(test1)

```

Features relevant to our analysis; Sales column is left as we are going to predict.

```{r}
variable.names <- names(train1)[c(1,2,6,7,8:12,14:23)]

for (f in variable.names) {
  if (class(train1[[f]])=="character") {
    levels <- unique(c(train1[[f]], test1[[f]]))
    train1[[f]] <- as.integer(factor(train1[[f]], levels=levels))
    test1[[f]]  <- as.integer(factor(test1[[f]],  levels=levels))
  }
}
```



// Random forest
```{r}
result <- randomForest(train1[,variable.names], 
                    log(train1$Sales+1),
                    mtry=5,
                    ntree=50,
                    max_depth = 30,
                    sampsize=150000,
                    do.trace=TRUE)

importance(result, type = 1)   
importance(result, type = 2)
varImpPlot(result)                 
pred <- exp(predict(result, test1)) -1
submission <- data.frame(Id=test$Id, Sales=pred)
write_csv(submission, "resultfile.csv")

```
````